# Is there a way to unlock my son's Galaxy Tab A (SM-T580) with Family Link?

Tags: password, google-family-link

My son has not used his Galaxy Tab A (SM-T580) for months and he has forgotten his 3x3 unlock pattern/password.  The tablet is linked to Family Link on my Samsung phone.  How do we access his device?

Comment: There's no "parent access" link from the lock screen? If so, https://support.google.com/families/answer/7307262